# function like in a select statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to implement a function-like functionality in a select statement.
I need to do something like this:

```
select ID, OwnerName(ManagerID), OwnerName(ManagerID2) from Table1;
```

Should OwnerName be a function or a Stored procedure. I know Stored Procedures can't be called in a Select Statement. Any suggestions How can I do that?

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  If this is a lookup, I would handle it in sql, not a UDF.

Comment: call the function ownerName in a select statement to get values for all records

Comment: I don't know about teradata, but in Oracle, a stored procedure does not return any values but a function does, so you can call certain functions from a SELECT

Comment: it has to be the function, procedure cannot be called in Select statement. You should be able to achieve this with the join statement too. can you elaborate more on your requirement ? May be with some sample data as well